# Javascript Autocomplete email's domain using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need help, I am stuck with trying to make the following case scenario work:
You have email input field, you type: foo@y - it should pop up autocomplete box, offering yahoo.com (for example).
If you take this suggestion, the end value should become: foo@yahoo.com

I have wrote this code (modified off another jquery UI sample):

```
        $( "#tags" )
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                            var mail_regex = /^([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)$/;
                            var match = mail_regex.exec(request.term);
                            if (match)
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + match[2], "i" );
                            response( $.grep( availableTags, function( item ){
                                return matcher.test( item );
                            }) );
                 },
                focus: function() {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var terms = split( this.value );
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push( ui.item.value );
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Full working interactive sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/rRF2s/3/

However, it REPLACES the foo@ with just yahoo.com - I can not for the life of me figure out how to override this behaviour...

Any Javascript/jQuery masters - help please! how to accomplish this goal?
I tried doing: return match[1]+matcher.test( item ), but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` function is assigning the resultant value with `this.value =`. However it is replacing the input value completely rather than appending it with the drop down value.

Without a great deal of testing the following, simplified function seems to work as required:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.indexOf('@') + 1) + ui.item.value;
    return false;
}
```

This is taking the first part of the already entered value, for example `foo@` for the input `foo@ya` and then adding on the value of the selected item from the drop down.

You may want to trigger the dropdown when someone enters the `@` symbol (seems more intuitive to me) and if so, this function may also need modifying to correctly extract the user entered value.

Comment: Thank you! I got the hang of it now :)
Could you please add an explanation how to set the trigger to @ symbol? currently I have it on having 3 chars minimum ("a@b") as trigger for the time being - that works but I am not happy with this method.

Comment: Sorry I did not have time to look at this further. If you are happy with the other solution do you need to trigger off the `@` still?

Comment: Thank you, but its ok what I have got so far is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "Yahoo.com",
        "Gmail.com"
    ];
    function extractLast( val ) {
        if (val.indexOf("@")!=-1){
            var tmp=val.split("@");
            console.log(tmp[tmp.length-1]);
            return tmp[tmp.length-1];
        }
        console.log("returning empty");
        return "";
    }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                        var mail = extractLast(request.term);
                        if(mail.length<1){return;}
                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + mail, "i" );
                        response( $.grep( availableTags, function( item ){
                            return matcher.test( item );
                        }));
             },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = this.value.split(", ");
                // remove the current input
                var ml=terms[terms.length-1].split("@")[0];
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ml+"@"+ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I have this for the select function:
<pre>
<code>
  select: function( event, ui ) {
   //var terms = split( this.value );
   var mail_regex = /^([\w\.]+)@([\w\.]+)$/;
   var match = mail_regex.exec(this.value);
   var Input = match[1]+"@"+ui.item.value;
   
   // remove the current input
   //terms.pop();
   // add the selected item
   //terms.push( Input );
   // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
   //terms.push( "" );
   //this.value = terms.join( ", " );
   this.value = Input;
   return false;
</code>
</pre>

Why to use the push thing? is my way not very good?

Comment: I will look at the code on jsfiddle, terms is an array used for autocompleting multiple words separated by a comma. Will change my answer to post full code to autocomplete multiple emails separated by a comma space