# jQuery autocomplete after specific key press

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How could I add event to use Autocomplete after keypress like @ or # (hashtags) and than format variants into links to insert?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552118/javascript-autocomplete-emails-domain-using-jquery-ui/ might help, which is about triggering the autocomplete after a `@` character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery for it: [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
auto_options = { 
    serviceUrl: '/getpincodes',
    width: 300,
    minChars:1,
    delimiter: /(@|#)\s,
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    type: "POST",
    isLocal:true,
    enable: true,
    onSelect: function(value, data){
        return data;
    },
    noCache: true //set to true, to disable caching
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#inputId').autocomplete(auto_options);
});
```